# Edit .sql files when comparing them with source control in VS 2012 (SSDT)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to compare my changes I made in .sql files with the older version from TFS. Is it possible to merge the files while comparing? They are opened in read-only mode (there is lock on the right side of the tab) and I can not merge changes. Is there any changes to get it working?